# Подключение к сетевому оборудованию с помощью Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть потребность в подключении к коммутаторам при помощи библиотек Python.
Большая доля оборудования от Allied Telesis, которая запрашивает два логина.
И если к остальному оборудованию можно подключиться при помощи Paramiko/Netmiko, то к данному оборудованию нет. Поэтому была выбрана библиотека pexpect/winpexpect, которая, к сожалению, на Windows не отрабатывает. Выдает ошибки:

> AttributeError: module 'pexpect' has no attribute 'spawn'
>
> ImportError: cannot import name 'spawn' from 'pexpect'

И при использовании `pexpect.popen_spawn.PopenSpawn` так же.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно реализовать подключение?

Comment: Ничего не понятно. По какому протоколу подключаетесь-то? Если по SSH, то чем Paramiko не подошёл? Где текст проблемного кода? При чём тут вообще pexpect? Гуглить «pexpect windows» пробовали? А ещё при чём тут networkx, который есть в метках, но никак не упомянут в тексте вопроса?

Comment: Если мой ответ Вам помог, отметьте его, пожалуйста, как принятый нажатием на `v` под счётчиком голосов.

Answer (score 0):

Могу поделиться куском рабочего класса. Он самодокументирован. Позволяет как подключиться, так и повысить привилегии, включив `enabled` режим.

Использует paramiko и работает из-под Windows.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# Standard modules
import re
import socket
import base64
import json
import operator

# Additional modules
import paramiko         # https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko

class DummyObject(object):
    """
    This is a dummy class allowing calling any method names with any arguments.
    Used for doing optional logging
    """
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return lambda *x: None

class DeviceCLI (object):
    """
    This class allows to connect and execute commands on a generic device.
    :param host: A device hostname/IP/FQDN
    :param username: Username to login into the device
    :param password: Password to login into the device
    :param timeout: The connection timeout in seconds
    :param logger: The logger instance
    :param enabled_pwd: Password for the enabled mode
    """
    #
    _tty_width = 200
    _tty_height = 24000
    _tty_term = 'xterm'
    # List of ESC codes to be removed from output
    _esc_to_clean = [ "\x1b[?1h","\x1b=","\x1b[" + str(_tty_height) + ";1H","\x1b[K","\x1b[?1l","\x1b>" ]
    # Regex to remove the ASCII codes from output
    _regex_clean = re.compile("(%s)" % "|".join(map(re.escape, _esc_to_clean)))

    def __init__(self, host, ip, username, password, timeout, logger=None, enabled_pwd=None):
        self.host = host
        self.ip = ip
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.timeout = timeout
        self.logger = logger or DummyObject()
        self.enabled_pwd = enabled_pwd
        self.ssh = None
        self.channel = None

    def connect(self):
        """
        Method to connect to the device
        Returns: interaction channel
        """
        self.logger.debug("{0}: Connecting...".format(self.host))
        # Create a new SSH client object
        self.ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()

        # Set SSH client to auto accept unknown hosts
        self.ssh.load_system_host_keys()
        self.ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

        # Connect to the host
        self.ssh.connect(self.ip, username=self.username, password=self.password)

        # Use invoke_shell to establish an 'interactive session'
        self.logger.debug("{0}: Invoking shell".format(self.host))
        self.channel = self.ssh.invoke_shell(term=self.__class__._tty_term, width=self.__class__._tty_width, height=self.__class__._tty_height)
        self.channel.settimeout(self.timeout)

        # Skip login info or timeout
        self.logger.debug("{0}: Skipping welcome output".format(self.host))
        self.wait_for_output(self.prompt)

        # Switching into enabled mode
        if self.enabled_pwd:
            self.logger.debug("{0}: Entering the enabled mode".format(self.host))
            self.channel.send('en\n')
            self.wait_for_output("Password:")
            self.channel.send(self.enabled_pwd+'\n')
            self.wait_for_output(self.prompt)

        # Returning the established channel
        self.logger.debug("{0}: Connected".format(self.host))
        return self.channel

    def receive_and_decode(self):
        return self.channel.recv(len(self.channel.in_buffer)).decode('latin-1')

    def wait_for_output(self, regex_to_wait):
        stdout = ""
        while True:
            try:
                stdout += self.receive_and_decode()
            except socket.timeout:
                msg = "Timeout waiting for device prompt. Report to support. Output received:\n{0}".format(stdout)
                self.logger.debug("{0} {1}".format(self.host, msg))
                raise RuntimeError(msg)
            if re.search(regex_to_wait + '$', stdout, re.DOTALL|re.IGNORECASE):
                break
```

Для Cisco:

```
class Cisco_CLI (cli.DeviceCLI):
    """
    This class allows to connect and execute commands on a Cisco device.
    :param host: A Cisco device hostname/IP/FQDN
    :param username: Username to login into the device
    :param password: Password to login into the device
    :param timeout: The connection timeout in seconds
    :param logger: The logger instance
    :param enabled_pwd: Password for the enabled mode
    """

    _cisco_prompt_regex = "{0}.*?(#|>)\s*"

    def __init__(self, host, ip, username, password, timeout, logger=None, enabled_pwd=None):
        cli.DeviceCLI.__init__(self, host, ip, username, password, timeout, logger, enabled_pwd)
        self.prompt = self.__class__._cisco_prompt_regex.format(re.escape(self.host))
# class
```

Comment: Можно попридираться?) Чем `re` более стандартный модуль чем `socket`, `base64`, `json`, `operator`?

Comment: @insolor можно. Это из разряда невычищенных тараканов. Кстати - это кусок файла, так что наверняка пара-тройка импортов - лишние для данного конкретного куска